# how to change input type in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have 2 fields one is `password` and another is `checkbox`

```
...
...
<input type="password" ng-model="data.password" id="form_password"></input>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.show_password" id="show_password"></input>
<label> Show Password</label>
...
...
```

When user click on `show_password` checkbox, I want to change `form_password` type to `text` so user can see the password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do the following:

```
<input ng-show="!data.show_password" type="password" ng-model="data.password" id="form_password">
<input ng-show="data.show_password" type="text" ng-model="data.password">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.show_password" id="show_password">
<label>Show Password</label>
```

(or obviously you could use `ng-hide`, stylistic preference)